Increase keyframe interval of static video without reencoding
I have a lot of videos downloaded from youtube that contain music plus either a static image or a slideshow of a few images. In theory, these videos shouldn't take up more space than just the audio plus a jpeg, but because they have keyframes every 5 seconds, they are taking up hundreds of MB each.
I know I can use ffmpeg with -g or -keyint to reduce the keyframes but as I understand it, that would reencode the video losing quality on the image. Is there a way to tell ffmpeg to convert keyframes to P or B frames without reencoding? Or what would be a good way to reduce the space taken up by these videos?

For a static image, it's possible to keep only (say 10%) of the keyframes, and adjust the framerate (note that it might affect the seeking capabilities). Slideshow is more complicated, because we have to find where the slide changes. Converting keyframes to P or B frames without re-encoding is not possible using FFmpeg.
